# Loading IFilterGraph from .GRF file with IPersistStream::Load fails to instantiate private in-process filters registered with CoRegisterClassObject

Tags: com, directshow

Loading Directshow IFilterGraphs from GRF files in the application works fine for normal filters which are registered globally in DLLs.

```
    // open structured storage file...
    hr = pStorage->OpenStream(L"ActiveMovieGraph", 0, STGM_READ | STGM_SHARE_EXCLUSIVE, 0, &pStream);
if (SUCCEEDED(hr)) {
    hr = pPersistStream->Load(pStream);
    pStream->Release();
}
```

However some filters are registered locally in the EXE using CoRegisterObject called from a IClassFactory implementation. These filters are created with C++ new when the IClassFactory implementation receives a IClassFactory::CreateInstance call.

```
    HRESULT hr = CoRegisterClassObject(*m_pTemplate->m_ClsID, this, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, REGCLS_MULTI_SEPARATE, &m_RegisterKey);
```

The local filters work fine when created directly through CoCreateInstance. They also work fine when created directly with C++ new.

```
CoCreateInstance(clsid, NULL, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, IID_IBaseFilter, (void**)&instance);
```

Loading GRF files that contain these local filters does not work and returns HRESULT 0x80040154 Class not registered from IPersistStream::Load.

The application's IClassFactory::CreateInstance function is not called but the CoCreateInstance API is called during IPersistStream::Load with the correct CLSID but it's called from a different thread than the IPersistStream::Load call (on the main application thread initialized with COM apartment threading). The other difference is that dwContext when called from IPersistStream::Load is CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER|CLSCTX_INPROC_HANDLER. However CoCreateInstance calls from the main thread still work with this dwContext value. CoRegisterClassObject calls including the CLSCTX_INPROC_HANDLER flag fail with E_INVALIDARG.

```
ole32.dll!CoCreateInstance(const _GUID & rclsid, IUnknown * pUnkOuter, unsigned long dwContext, const _GUID & riid, void * * ppv)  Line 96  C++
quartz.dll!_CoCreateFilter@8()  + 0x1a bytes    
quartz.dll!CFilterGraph::OnCreateFilter()  + 0x55 bytes 
quartz.dll!CFGControl::CGraphWindow::OnReceiveMessage()  + 0x2d05 bytes 
quartz.dll!WndProc()  + 0x3e bytes  
user32.dll!_InternalCallWinProc@20()  + 0x23 bytes  
user32.dll!_UserCallWinProcCheckWow@32()  + 0xb7 bytes  
user32.dll!_DispatchMessageWorker@8()  + 0xed bytes 
user32.dll!_DispatchMessageW@4()  + 0xf bytes   
quartz.dll!ObjectThread()  + 0x65 bytes 
kernel32.dll!@BaseThreadInitThunk@12()  + 0x12 bytes    
ntdll.dll!___RtlUserThreadStart@8()  + 0x27 bytes   
ntdll.dll!__RtlUserThreadStart@8()  + 0x1b bytes    

rclsid  {CA6B3460-28B3-4A6E-A7FC-A83CF1DEEC49}  const _GUID &
pUnkOuter   0x00000000  IUnknown *
dwContext   3   unsigned long
riid    {IID_IBaseFilter}   const _GUID &
```

The application calls CoInitializeEx(NULL, COINIT_APARTMENTTHREADED) as recommended for MFC applications. I've tried using different context and flags values in the call to CoRegisterClassObject without success. The GRF file definitely contains the correct CLSID for the process-local filter.

The behaviour is the same with Win32 and x64 builds of the application. The host OS is Windows 7 x64.

Does IFilterGraph serialization support process-local filters registered with CoRegisterClassObject? If so is there a problem with what the application is doing? Are there any steps I can take to diagnose this issue further?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the benefit of future readers this solved the problem:

Call CoRegisterClassObject from every apartment that will CoCreateInstance process local COM objects.

To use CLSID_FilterGraph to load GRF files and instantiate locally registered filters that also means calling CoRegisterClassObject from any one of the MTA threads in the application and making sure that at least one MTA thread is running at all times otherwise the registration seems to die.

The simplest way to do this in a STA application (though possibly wasteful) is to start a thread which calls CoInitializeEx(NULL, COINIT_MULTITHREADED) then CoRegisterClassObject then Sleeps and never exits.

There's a helpful MSDN explanation of COM apartments at [Understanding and Using COM Threading Models](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms809971.aspx)

Comment: A small update on this: there is only one MTA per process. It is sufficient to register on *any* MTA thread, not on *every*. This includes even creating a temp thread, joining it to MTA, just for the purpose of `CoRegisterClassObject` call.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, Roman. I did mean from 'any' MTA thread rather than from 'each and every' MTA thread but my wording wasn't completely clear. The point about keeping an MTA apartment alive is also important - the simplest way to ensure this in my particular app was to create a dedicated MTA thread for this purpose which calls CoRegisterClass then Sleeps.

Comment: Oh yes, you wrote it right in first place :) My bad, I did not read good enough.

Comment: Not at all, my original wording was ambiguous :)

Answer (score 2):

I would say that the whole `.GRF` file story is not supposed for production use. It is just a helpful option for debugging, development, troubleshooting. And here you are hitting one of the limitations that are not well outlined on the documentation due to limited intended use in first place.

The filter graph expects a filter to be hosted by a DLL (with the class marked with `Both` apartment model) and as such it issues `CoCreateInstance` call with the arguments you see. Additionally, if you are using `CLSID_FilterGraph` filter graph, as MSDN says, it:

> Creates the Filter Graph Manager on a shared worker thread.

And then you see instantiation calls on a thread where you don't expect them.

I would say you can still make it work with reasonable effort. First of all, you need to try `CLSID_FilterGraphNoThread` instead to resolve the threading problem, and have the instantiation calls occur on the calling thread, in the apartment you already prepared with your `CoRegisterClassObject` calls.

Once the threading problem is resolved, `CLSCTX` should not be a problem. `CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER` is good enough, and you are choosing the context flags in the `CoRegisterClassObject` calls so it should be sufficient to prepare COM context and have your class factory called from withing the .GRF loading internals.

If you are creating graph from UI thread, or otherwise a thread which has a message loop as a part of its normal operation, `CLSID_FilterGraphNoThread` should work equally goods as regular `CLSID_FilterGraph`. `CLSID_FilterGraphNoThread` is basically a rare bird, but Windows Media Player does use it internally, and perhaps it is the reason why this variant of filter graph class exists at all.

Comment: Thanks, Roman. Using CLSID_FilterGraphNoThread solves the problem. Presumably to make it work with CLSID_FilterGraph I'd need to find a way to run my CoRegisterClassObject code from the filter graph thread - perhaps I could call a filter graph manager function which calls back to some of my own code and call CoRegisterClassObject from there.

Comment: As an idea - you can add a fake filter so that Filter Graph Manager would call some of its methods on the right thread. Then you can even remove the filter out of there before completing graph building and running the graph.

Comment: After some experiments it looks like I just need to call  CoRegisterClassObject from every apartment that will CoCreateInstance process local COM objects. To use CLSID_FilterGraph that also means calling CoRegisterClassObject from any MTA thread in the application and making sure that at least one MTA thread is running at all times otherwise the registration seems to die. The simplest way to do this in a STA application (though possibly wasteful) is to start a thread which calls CoInitializeEx(NULL, COINIT_MULTITHREADED) then CoRegisterClassObject then Sleeps and never exits.